# Windows Forms: редактирование вложенных Control в сложном User Control через Designer родительской формы

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, usercontrol

Имеется `User Control`, включающий в себя стандартные `Controls`. Добавляем этот `User Control` на форму через Designer. Как посредством дизайнера изменять  внутренние `Controls` этого `User Control`?

Атрибут
`[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]` частично решает проблему: изменять значения внутренних Controls можно, НО только через окошко свойств UserControl. Как сделать так, чтобы при щелчке в дизайнере на внутренний Control открывалось его окно свойств и можно было бы редактировать прямо на форме (к примеру как можно добавлять элементы MenuStrip, не используя окно свойств)? Возможно ли это?

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Если уж вы создаете сложные компоненты, которые хотите редактировать в дизайнере, то смотрите книгу "Разработка компонентов в MS Visual Studio", Павел Агуров.